# Как образовать прилагательное от название города Ницца?

Tags: словообразование

Собственно, интересует вопрос, как же правильно образовать прилагательное от так мною любимого города Ницца? Погуглив, нашёл вариант «ниццкий», но он кажется мне, простите, настолько уродливым, что я бы не стал его употреблять. Есть ли какие-то рекомендации/словарные нормы по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чисто интуитивно я бы написал **"ниццианский"** (по созвучию с **"венецианским"**), но в международном праве все-таки закрепилось написание **"ниццкий"** (см.["ниццкий договор"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80)). На этот же вариант указывает и [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2424):

> 8. В прилагательных, образованных от географических названий с производящей основой на -ц, пишется:
>    <...>
>    3) -цц-к-, если перед ц стоит ц: **ниццкий** ← **Ницца**.